# What is the best way to record a user lab that includes multiple devices?

Tags: usability-testing, responsive-design, tools

I have always used porgrammes such as Morae or Silverback to record user labs, but I'd like to test different breakpoints on a responsive site using actual devices. How do I record tests on tablets and mobile devices? Any advice?:)